# Why member plugin for linkedln is not working?

Tags: linkedin-api

Input fields like profile url,dataformat are not visible  for generation of specific code on developer page.

Tried with following code :
`<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/in/dummy" data-format="inline"></script>`
still no result.

Does it need to be tested online?
Tested with jsfiddle and other's but still not working?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile-plugin-generator
2. The profile needs to set an URL "Your public profile URL" under the Profile settings. If none is set, the preview will appear empty.

Hope that helps